# count every ten seconds using excel and Visual Basic

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to count every ten seconds in a column in excel using Visual Basic
what code do I have to write in order to repeat this function every ten seconds [enter image description here][1]

this is my cloumn I am trying to write in column (k) which ten seconds are they
for example : the first ten seconds are number 1 so in column k appears number one, the seconde ten seconds are number two.....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XIIt.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im trynig to summum every ten seconds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you want to achieve, but it sounds like you want to run a timer with an interval of 10 seconds, and every time it runs, you want to alter the next row or column of a table. If so, something like this should work:

```
Class MyClass
    Private NbElapsed As Integer = 1
    Private WithEvents TenSecondTimer As New System.Timers.Timer(10000) With { .AutoReset = True }
    Private SC As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

    Private Sub TenSecondTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RestrictionTimer.Elapsed
        SC.Post(AddressOf Elapsed, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Elapsed(args as Object = Nothing)
        NbElapsed += 1
        ' TODO: Alter column with index NbElapsed
    End Sub
End Class
```